# Not able to access stored procedure from my application

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have written few stored procedures and executed in my server that is having  php myadmin  now while calling this stored procedure from my application  it is showing
following exception

```
SQLException1 java.sql.SQLException: User does not have access to metadata required to 
determine stored procedure parameter types. If rights can not be granted, configure 
connection with "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver generate parameters that 
represent INOUT strings irregardless of actual parameter types.
```

While searching i find following query to resolve this exception:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON mysql.proc TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

my problem is that while running this query i am getting following error

```
#1142 - SELECT,INSERT,UP command denied to user 'qqq'@'localhost' for table 'proc'
```

but i have given all permission to user

```
 GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'qqq'@'localhost';
```

So how to access stored procedure from my application
I am using shared hosting server .

Comment: Thanks for this!  This is the first hit on Google for `mysql.proc stored procedure permission`, and all I needed was the command.

Answer (score 2):

The error you provided is generated by your driver. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986628/cant-execute-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-java) question, which points you to [a blog entry](http://sql.dzone.com/tips/quick-tip-grating-access-meta-) giving an answer. To sum it up, you have two options:

1. The GRANT statement you tried
2. adding noAccessToProcedureBodies=true to your database connection string (which is also suggested by the error message)

Since you are using a shared hosting server it is likely that you don't have privileges on mysql.proc and you don't have root access to the server, so you can't GRANT them. Therefore you should try the second approach.

Comment: I also tried 2nd option `String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?user=user_name&password=password&noAccessToProcedureBodies=true";` and
            `Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);`     but still showing same error.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked for me in mysql

Step 1 : add/edit following
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/logparser?noAccessToProcedureBodies = true ", "root", "");

Step 2 : Execute following query
GRANT ALL ON logparser.proc TO root@'%'; 
where logparser is DB name and proc is procedure name.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and I have tried above solutions nothing worked.
Adding Global Privilege `SELECT` worked.

Environment: MySQL 8.x
InnoDB
Aurora MySQL